# Ruby on Rails vs. Django

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails or Django? (or something else?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91846/rails-or-django-or-something-else)

These are two web frameworks that are becoming (or have been in many circles) popular. I was wondering what are the advantages and disadvantages of each? Feel free to comment on Ruby and Python pros and cons also.

Two disadvantages I am speculative about for RoR is the scalability, since it still seems to be a disputable topic, and how turbulent the 'in' libraries are?

Comment: Please make this community wiki.

Comment: I'm actually curious on this topic as well. I haven't done any research in it yet.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many questions, one of which is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91846/rails-or-django-or-something-else

Answer (score 9):

Watch Google Talk "Snakes and Rubies" on [video.google.com](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2939556954580527226). Core developers from Django and Ruby on Rails comparing these two frameworks. In better quality [here](http://www.djangoproject.com/snakesandrubies/)

Comment: Er... That video only talks about Django. Is there a matching one for RoR that I just can't find?

Comment: My bad. I was talking about this video "Snakes and Rubies": http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2939556954580527226. I'm going to fix url in my post.

Comment: Also you can compare list of the books for Django and RoR: http://push.cx/2009/django-vs-rails-the-dead-tree-edition

Comment: YouTube Link : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cb9KDt9aXc8